# use kinect camera as a webcam in ubuntu

Tags: python, webcam, opengl, microsoft, opencv

I have a python openCV program that uses a webcam to track an image target. I switched computers, but this new computer does not have a webcam. I hooked up my kinect, installed stome stuff from OpenKinect.org (can now use `glview`), and would like to use the Kinect camera as a webcam for this program. How can I do this? The program I wrote is:
http://pastebin.com/usspQXNU

Answer (score 4):

Newer kernels (3.0 or higher IIRC) [support](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1123824) using the Kinect's RGB camera as a regular webcam. Suppose the Kinect camera is /dev/video0, you can run this command to get a video stream:

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

That means OpenCV's `highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(0)` should also just work (with 0 as the id  for the Kinect camera).

You can check if the modules are loaded with this command:

```
$ lsmod | grep -i gspca
gspca_kinect           12936  0
gspca_main             28366  1 gspca_kinect
videodev               98259  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you https://github.com/wildbillcat/KinectCam/

One more thing, I have same problem but with kinect v2 not kinect v1